# Kendo UI createlink and insertimage popup modal does not show input box

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo text editor. In tools, I have added the required custom tools. Currently, ***createLink and insertImage*** tools pops up the window but does not show input text boxes. When checked in the inspect mode, the required div can be seen but because of some reason, they are not getting rendered.

```
        let tools: any = [
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            'createLink',
            'unlink',
            "formatting",
            "cleanFormatting",
            'fontName',
            'fontSize',
            'foreColor',
            'justifyLeft',
            'justifyCenter',
            'justifyRight'
        ];
        var data = valueAccessor();
        $(element).kendoEditor({

            resizable: {
                content: true,
                toolbar: true
            },
            change: (ev) => {
                valueAccessor()($(element).data("kendoEditor").value());
            },
            tools: tools
        });
        var editor = $(element).data("kendoEditor");
        if (data !== null) {
            editor.value(data());
        }
        const isHtmlElement = (el: any): el is HTMLElement => el.style !== undefined;

        if (isHtmlElement(editor.body)) {
            $(editor.body).addClass("k-editor-override");
       }
    }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z85Tq.png)

[Inspect mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCUei.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**display: none !important** rule was set in .**k-edit-label .k-edit-field .k-imagebrowser** class because of previous requirement. Removing this rule solved the issue for me.